# Sorting by date returns empty query

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to group information in a SQL Database (Using MYSQL) through a php script. Here's my function that I wrote. (Today is my first day with php, technically second)

```
function getQuery($ResultType, $tbl_name, $Date) {
    if($ResultType == 'Day') { return "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where Date($tbl_name.Date) = DATE('$Date')"; }
    if($ResultType == 'Year') { return "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where Year($tbl_name.Date) = Year('$Date')" ; }     
    if($ResultType == 'Month') { return "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where Year($tbl_name.Date) = Year('$Date') and Month($tbl_name.Date) = Month($Date)"; }
}
```

When trying to get the data by "Day" or "Year" it works, but the query that is trying to select everything for that month is returning 0 rows.

Date is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd if it matters.

Comment: Can you show values of $Date and value stored in Date column?

Comment: Values stored in the $Date colum of the Database? It's the DATE format in yyyy-mm-dd.

Date being used as $DATE, is also just a textbox showing yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing quote in the last query. Change

```
 Month($Date)
```

to

```
 Month('$Date')
```